# How to Install slurm in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04

I would like to install slurm in ubuntu 20.04 in my PC? Can someone list the steps I am required to do for that?

Thanks.

Comment: -1 lack of research. Try the slurm website. Or `apt search slurm`. Or `snap search slurm`.

Answer (score 3):

The slurm [website](https://slurm.schedmd.com/download.html) points to [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=slurm-wlm) page, and the name of the package is `slurm-wlm`.

Open a terminal and enter the command

```
sudo apt install slurm-wlm
```

Comment: and then, several steps are missing, just installing a packge does not mean it can be run

Comment: @GregorvonLaszewski I don't use this software myself. The question was about installation. Feel free to edit my answer to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, in my opinion, to get slurm running locally is by using the slurm charms developed by Omnivector.

[Here](https://omnivector-solutions.github.io/osd-documentation/master/) it is a very detailed documentation we put in place that might cover everything you need to get it going.